# Django: NoReverseMatch at /home/blog/ Reverse for 'post-detail' not found. 'post-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have been getting this error, and I didn't know what I did wrong in the code, I checked everything and I still cant figure it out. I also try getting the specific post object in the database by id, i mean doing something like "post = Post.objects.get(id=id)" in post function in my views.py, but i got the same error.
Any help will be appreciated.

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse


User = get_user_model()


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    overview = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

my urls

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import home, blog, post


app_name = 'blog'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home-page'),
    path('blog/', blog, name='blogs'),
    path('post/<id>/', post, name='post-detail'),
]
```

my blog.html template

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          {% for post in queryset %}
            <div class="post col-xl-6">
              <div class="post-thumbnail">
                <a href="post.html"><img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="post-details">
                <div class="post-meta d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <div class="category">
                  {% for cat in post.categories.all %}
                  <a href="#">{{cat}}</a>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
                  <h3 class="h4">{{post.title}}</h3>
                </a>
                <p class="text-muted">{{post.overview}}</p>
                <footer class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center">
                  <a href="#" class="author d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                    <div class="avatar">
                      <img src="{{post.author.profile_pic.url}}" alt="..." class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                      <span>{{post.author.user.username}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <div class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i>{{post.timestamp|timesince}} ago</div>
                  <div class="comments meta-last"><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{post.comment_count}}</div>
                </footer>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- Pagination -->
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination pagination-template d-flex justify-content-center">
            {% if queryset.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a href="?page={{queryset.previous_page_number}}" class="page-link">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{queryset.number}}" class="page-link active">{{queryset.number}}</a></li>
            {% if queryset.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a href="?page={{queryset.next_page_number}}" class="page-link">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from blog.models import Post, Category
from marketing.models import Signup


def home(request):
    featured_posts = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    latest_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email
        new_signup.save()

    context = {
        'featured_posts': featured_posts,
        'latest_posts': latest_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def blog(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    latest_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 4)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.get_page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.get_page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'post_list': post_list,
        'queryset': queryset,
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)



def post(request, id):
    
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py change the `get_absolute_url` as follow. You need to include the **app name** also before calling any specific url from an app.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

Comment: Thanks, i included the app name and it worked

Comment: dear, you should accept the answer to say thanks if this solves the problem..[How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If it's a hint in solving problem then an upvote.